# Redshift SQL, concatinate sting and year

Tags: mysql, string, date, type-conversion

I have 2 variables: month and year.
Month is a string and looks like: Mar, Apr, May, Jun, etc...
Year is a number: 2019, 2020

I tried to concatinate both but it showed me a syntax error.

```
`month`||`-`||`year` as Month_Year
```

What I want to get is either Month-YYYY or 
DD-MM-YYYY

```
current_date - Interval '1 Month'
```

But in Redshift SQL language
To make it more clear, I try to generate the 3rd column. With respect to the current date:
[image]

Comment: what DD would you expect in DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with mysql

Comment: it is a dynamic chart, in that case the current date. So today it would be 27-03-2020, and I want that to be adjusted for the previous 12 months. Meaning 27-03-2020, 27-02-2020, 27-01-2020 etc

Comment: @kris030 your last comment makes things less clear. please add sample data and expected outcome to the question as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon I added a table and hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't use `||` as concatenation operator. Instead use the `concat()` function. And string literal need to be enclosed in single quotes, not backticks.

```
concat(`month`, '-', `year`)
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you would use now() as todays date , pull off the day and concat month and year this won't result in a valid mysql date which is in the form yyyy-mm-dd.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(yr int,mth varchar(3));

insert into t values
(2019,'Nov'),
(2019,'Dec'),
(2020,'Jan'),
(2020,'Feb'),
(2020,'Mar');


select concat(day(now()),'-',mth,'-',yr)
from t;

+-----------------------------------+
| concat(day(now()),'-',mth,'-',yr) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 27-Nov-2019                       |
| 27-Dec-2019                       |
| 27-Jan-2020                       |
| 27-Feb-2020                       |
| 27-Mar-2020                       |
+-----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Don't forget you will need to code for leap years..